# Command to open "Stream from MEGA" window directly

Tags: linux, command-line, window, mega

The Mega desktop application (of mega.nz cloud storage service) has an option to stream its cloud data through a specific window called “Stream from MEGA”. On my Linux Plasma desktop it can be opened by left-clicking the panel icon, then clicking a 3-dot button, then “Stream” option:

[image]

[image]

I would like to be able to open that window directly with one action/command, thus with a shortcut etc.

---

Using `xprop` I see this:

```
xprop WM_CLASS 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "megasync", "MEGAsync"

xprop _NET_STARTUP_ID 
Al_NET_STARTUP_ID :  no such atom on any window.
```

Also:

```
xwininfo

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x360002a "Stream from MEGA"

  Absolute upper-left X:  829
  Absolute upper-left Y:  196
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 420
  Height: 303
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x2c2
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x360001a (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +829+196  -191+196  -191-401  +829-401
  -geometry 420x303+829+196

xprop -id 0x360002a | grep PID
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1924

ps aux | grep 1924
cip         1924  0.4  3.8 1830624 153500 ?      Ssl  08:48   0:03 /usr/bin/megasync
cip         4274  0.0  0.0   9060  2264 pts/1    S+   09:03   0:00 grep --color=auto 1924
```

---

(I am posting here instead of Unix & Linux in case the solution works for Windows too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most that can be achieved here is that running `megasync` while the app is already running pops up the first window. Thus, we don't have to click the tray icon (which can stay hidden in this way) and a shortcut can be used for that. But it doesn't seem to be a way to get directly, with one command, what the question specifically asks.

---

A very limited and Linux-specific workaround, which doesn't involve keyboard shortcuts, but tray icons/buttons and the `kdocker` tool (able to "dock to tray" any window), is to send to tray the "Stream from MEGA" window (even add a per-app specific icon for the tray entry, different from the main Mega tray icon) and keep it there, open. Then, just click it to hide or show.

The command to "dock" a window to tray in this way is `kdocker -f -q`.

That command can be used with a shortcut or even with a panel button/launcher, like for example, in Plasma/KDE:

[image]

[image]

Kdocker can create separate tray *buttons* for each window, but can use a single icon *image* per application: different windows of the same application will have separate buttons, but these buttons will look the same:

[image]

[image]

[image]